# rollapplyr() creates only one new column instead of multiple columns for each column in .SDcols

Tags: r, data.table, rollapply

I am trying to use `rollapplyr()` on a data table an use it to generate various columns via `.SDcols`. Rather than putting the results for one column next to the results for another column, however, `rollapplyr()` stacks the results for each column below one another. Below some code to illustrate what I mean:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

cars <- data.table(mtcars)[, c('cyl', 'mpg', 'hp')]
setorder(cars, cyl)
maCols <- c('mpg_ma', 'hp_ma')
cars[, rollapplyr(.SD, mean, width = 3, align = 'right', partial = TRUE), 
     by = cyl, 
     .SDcols = c('mpg', 'hp')]
```

This code generates a data.table of two columns (cyl and V1) of 64 rows rather than a data table of three columns (cyl, V1 and V2) of 32 columns. Is there a way to obtain the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
cars[, lapply(.SD, function(x) rollapplyr(x, mean, width = 3, align = 'right', partial = TRUE)), 
     by = cyl, 
     .SDcols = c('mpg', 'hp')]
```

Output:

```
    cyl      mpg        hp
 1:   4 22.80000  93.00000
 2:   4 23.60000  77.50000
 3:   4 23.33333  83.33333
 4:   4 26.53333  74.33333
 5:   4 28.53333  71.00000
 6:   4 32.23333  61.00000
 7:   4 28.60000  71.33333
 8:   4 27.56667  76.00000
 9:   4 24.93333  84.66667
10:   4 27.90000  90.00000
11:   4 25.93333 104.33333
12:   6 21.00000 110.00000
13:   6 21.00000 110.00000
14:   6 21.13333 110.00000
15:   6 20.16667 108.33333
16:   6 19.56667 112.66667
17:   6 18.36667 117.00000
18:   6 18.90000 140.33333
19:   8 18.70000 175.00000
20:   8 16.50000 210.00000
21:   8 16.46667 200.00000
22:   8 16.00000 201.66667
23:   8 16.30000 180.00000
24:   8 14.30000 188.33333
25:   8 12.00000 200.00000
26:   8 11.83333 216.66667
27:   8 13.53333 198.33333
28:   8 15.13333 176.66667
29:   8 14.66667 181.66667
30:   8 15.90000 190.00000
31:   8 16.10000 228.00000
32:   8 16.66667 258.00000
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `lapply` to loop over selected columns in `.SDcols` and use `maCols` to assign the values to.

```
cars[, (maCols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
  zoo::rollapplyr(x, mean, width = 3, align = 'right', partial = TRUE)), 
  by = cyl, 
 .SDcols = c('mpg', 'hp')]

cars
#    cyl  mpg  hp mpg_ma hp_ma
# 1:   4 22.8  93   22.8  93.0
# 2:   4 24.4  62   23.6  77.5
# 3:   4 22.8  95   23.3  83.3
# 4:   4 32.4  66   26.5  74.3
# 5:   4 30.4  52   28.5  71.0
# 6:   4 33.9  65   32.2  61.0
# 7:   4 21.5  97   28.6  71.3
# 8:   4 27.3  66   27.6  76.0
# 9:   4 26.0  91   24.9  84.7
#10:   4 30.4 113   27.9  90.0
#....
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `rollapplyr` produces a matrix whereas data.table expects a  list, data.frame or data.table.  Just convert it and you should be ok.  Also you don't need `align = "right"` if  you use `rollapplyr` with an `r` on the end.

```
cars[, as.data.table(rollapplyr(.SD, mean, width = 3, partial = TRUE)), 
     by = cyl, 
     .SDcols = c('mpg', 'hp')]
```